# Pylance don't work in my root folder, but work in other folder. Why did this happen?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I use VSCode write my code in remote Linux Server with Python and Pylance extensions. but the Pylance don't work in my root folder, like this:

Pylance don't work, the color of import module don't change

[image: X]

However, when i change my workspace folder, it works, like this:

Pylance can work, the color of import module changed and it recognized 'cv2' module didn't import
[image: X]

I want to know why it happened and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you install and enable the Python extension on your remote session? Did you select the linter?

Comment: Yes, the Pylance work in other folder under the root

Comment: your second image is not an SSH workspace

Comment: Add namespace `import cv2`.

Comment: the workspace in second image is 'Code' folder in first image

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check Python Interpreter**: Make sure you have selected the correct Python interpreter for your workspace. You can do this by using shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **Python: Select Interpreter** to choose your python interpter.
2. **Check User Settings**: Open your user settings by going to `File > Preferences > Settings` and make sure the `Python › Analysis: Enabled` setting is checked.

If you're still facing issues after trying these steps, it might be a bug in the Pylance extension.
In that case, you might want to report the issue on the [Pylance GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues).